# Regex on command line to replace and reorder

Tags: regex, perl, sed

I have to follow text:

```
 30/01/2017 00:00:00                 158
 30/01/2017 00:30:00                 158
 30/01/2017 01:00:00                 158
 30/01/2017 01:30:00                 158
 30/01/2017 02:00:00                 158
 30/01/2017 02:30:00                 158
 30/01/2017 03:00:00                 158
 30/01/2017 03:30:00                 158
 30/01/2017 04:00:00                 158
 30/01/2017 04:30:00                 158
 30/01/2017 05:00:00                 158
 30/01/2017 05:30:00                 158
 30/01/2017 06:00:00                 158
 30/01/2017 06:30:00                 157
 30/01/2017 07:00:00                 157
 30/01/2017 07:30:00                 157
 30/01/2017 08:00:00                 157
```

I want using regex to reorder date in ISO format and convert to .csv file.

I allred test this commands:

```
perl -pe 's/(\s)([0-9]{2})\/([0-9]{2})\/([0-9]{4})\s([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})(\s+)(.*)/$4-$3-$2_$5;$7;931;2/g' file.txt > output.csv
```

and

```
sed -E 's/(\s)([0-9]{2})\/([0-9]{2})\/([0-9]{4})\s([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})(\s+)(.*)/\4-\3-\2_\5;\7;931;2/g' file.txt > output.csv
```

Expected result was to be:

```
2017-01-30_00:00:00;158;931;2
2017-01-30_00:30:00;158;931;2
2017-01-30_01:00:00;158;931;2
2017-01-30_01:30:00;158;931;2
2017-01-30_02:00:00;158;931;2
2017-01-30_02:30:00;158;931;2
2017-01-30_03:00:00;158;931;2
2017-01-30_03:30:00;158;931;2
2017-01-30_04:00:00;158;931;2
2017-01-30_04:30:00;158;931;2
2017-01-30_05:00:00;158;931;2
2017-01-30_05:30:00;158;931;2
2017-01-30_06:00:00;158;931;2
2017-01-30_06:30:00;157;931;2
2017-01-30_07:00:00;157;931;2
2017-01-30_07:30:00;157;931;2
2017-01-30_08:00:00;157;931;2
```

But the result is:

```
;931;21-30_00:00:00;158
;931;21-30_00:30:00;158
;931;21-30_01:00:00;158
;931;21-30_01:30:00;158
;931;21-30_02:00:00;158
;931;21-30_02:30:00;158
;931;21-30_03:00:00;158
;931;21-30_03:30:00;158
;931;21-30_04:00:00;158
;931;21-30_04:30:00;158
;931;21-30_05:00:00;158
;931;21-30_05:30:00;158
;931;21-30_06:00:00;158
;931;21-30_06:30:00;157
;931;21-30_07:00:00;157
;931;21-30_07:30:00;157
;931;21-30_08:00:00;157
```

Note ** 931; 2 ** at the beginning, but it was to be at the end. And even ate a part of 2017.

Why does it happen?

Comment: Your Perl produces the expected result for me. Also, did you know that `[0-9]` is `\d`? And that you can use other delimiters, like `s!a!b!` not to have to escape all `/`?

Comment: Works pretty fine for me.

Comment: A shorter oneliner: `perl -pe 's~\s(\d{2})/(\d{2})/(\d{4})\s(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\s+(.*)~$3-$2-$1_$4;$5;931;2~' file.txt > output.csv`

Comment: `perl -pe 's!\s(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)\s((\d+:?)+)\s+(.*)!$3-$2-$1_$4;$6;931;2!' file.txt > output.csv` to make even shorter @Toto :)

Comment: Your input file has `\r\n` newlines. That's what is sending ";931;2" to the start of the string. In perl, do `s/\s+$//` to remove trailing whitespace.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is almost certainly that you are using Linux to process a file that originated on a Windows system, which has CR LF line endings. The `.*` at the end of your regex pattern matches the CR right after the last number on each line (but not the LF) and so retains it in `$7` and inserts it into the output. That makes `;931;2` appear at the beginning of the line, overwriting the characters that were there before

One way to approach this is just to replace `chomp` with `s/\R\z//` which will match any of CR, LF, or CR LF at the end of the lines, and so handle the line endings of any system

Your regex is correct, but I would simply gather all numeric fields from each record and use `printf` to reformat the output. That way there is no need to remove the line ending in the first place

It would look like this

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

open my $fh, '<', 'data.txt' or die $!;

while ( <$fh> ) {
    my @F = /\d+/ag;
    printf "%04d-%02d-%02d_%02d:%02d:%02d;%d;%d;%d\n",
            @F[2,1,0,3,4,5,6], 931, 2;
}
```

#### output

```
2017-01-30_00:00:00;158;931;2
2017-01-30_00:30:00;158;931;2
2017-01-30_01:00:00;158;931;2
2017-01-30_01:30:00;158;931;2
2017-01-30_02:00:00;158;931;2
2017-01-30_02:30:00;158;931;2
2017-01-30_03:00:00;158;931;2
2017-01-30_03:30:00;158;931;2
2017-01-30_04:00:00;158;931;2
2017-01-30_04:30:00;158;931;2
2017-01-30_05:00:00;158;931;2
2017-01-30_05:30:00;158;931;2
2017-01-30_06:00:00;158;931;2
2017-01-30_06:30:00;157;931;2
2017-01-30_07:00:00;157;931;2
2017-01-30_07:30:00;157;931;2
2017-01-30_08:00:00;157;931;2
```

In a one-liner that would be

```
perl -ne '@F = /\d+/ag; printf "%04d-%02d-%02d_%02d:%02d:%02d;%d;%d;%d\n", @F[2,1,0,3,4,5,6], 931, 2;' myfile
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/^.(..).(..).(....).(........)\s*(\S*).*/\3-\2-\1_\4;\5;931;2/' file
```

Comment: There is an extra `.` after `^`.

Comment: @SLePort yes from copy/paste of the original data there is a space then the data in dd/mm/yyyy format. However in the required format there is no such space.

Comment: You're right, I didn't see it. It's a quite readable solution for a sed one... I didn't downvoted and I can only "reset" your score.